# Bingo 90 Strip Generator (UK Version)

Tags: probability, combinatorial-designs

The rules of the Bingo UK Game:

- there are 90 bingo balls.
- A bingo ticket consists of 9 columns and 3 rows. For each ticket:

  - A row contains exactly five numbers and four blanks.
  - A column consists of one, two or three numbers and never three blanks.
  - The columns are occupied by the number chosen from 1-9 (only nine), 10-19 (ten), 20-29 ... 70-79 and importantly 80-90 (eleven).
  - Numbers in columns are ordered from top to bottom.
- a strip consists of 6 bingo tickets, such that a strip contains all 90 bingo balls.

I am trying to figure out how to generate random strips based on the probabilities of numbers.

What I tried:

First I replaced all numbers from 1 to 90 with 1 and all spaces with -1, and I tried to calculate the probabilities of me getting a 1, following all the rules of the game.
I got that in order to get a 1 in the first column, the first row there is a 5/9 probability for row and a 9/18 probability for column. These probabilities decrease when I get a 1.
After I would correctly place the 1s on the bingo board I would replace them with the randomly generated number.

1) Is my strategy of replacing all numbers with 1s and -1s correct, or do I also have to consider the probabilities of for example, getting first a 2 instead of a 3  in the first column?

2) What is the formula for calculating the probabilities for these numbers? I do not know if my solution is correct or how to calculate the probabilities of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS INCORRECT**

As pointed out by Daniel Mathias, I overlooked the requirement that each row have exactly $4$ blanks.  I don't see any practical way of doing this if each pattern of blanks is to have an equal chance of occurrence.  The number of possible patterns is very large, I think, and I do't see how to generate a strip so that all strips have equal chance of occurrence.

I don't think you are going about it in the most effective way.  I think you should consider generating the entire strip, column by column.  For the first column, there are $18$ cells, $9$ of which will be blank, subject to the condition that not all three cells on a single ticket can be blank.

Choose $9$ elements from $18$, without replacement.  If numbers $1,2,3$ or $4,5,6$, etc. are all picked reject the sample and try again.  When you have a valid distribution of the blanks, generate a random permutation of the numbers from $1$ to $9$, using a random shuffle algorithm.  Distribute the numbers into the non-blank cells, in order.  Finally, sort the numbers that fall on the same ticket into increasing order.

Then do a similar thing for each of the remaining columns in turn.

I wrote a python script that works along the lines I suggested.

```
import random

cells = list(range(18))
cols = 9*[None]
cols[0] = list(range(1, 10))
for j in range(1, 8):
    cols[j] = list(range(10*j, 10*(j+1)))
cols[8] = list(range(80,91))

def blanks(k):
    while True:
        sample = random.sample(cells, k)
        for n in range(0,18,3):
            if all(x in sample for x in (n,n+1,n+2)):
                break
        else:  # loop else
            return sorted(sample)

def column(n):
    # generate column n for all tickets
    answer = 18*[-1]
    blank = blanks(18-len(cols[n]))
    for b in blank:
        answer[b] = 0
    random.shuffle(cols[n])
    index = 0
    for n in cols[n]:
        while answer[index] == 0:
            index += 1
        answer[index] = n
        index += 1
    for tkt in range(6):
        col = answer[3*tkt:3*(tkt+1)]
        blank = col.count(0)
        assert blank != 3
        if blank == 0:
            answer[3*tkt:3*(tkt+1)]=sorted(col)
        if blank == 1:
            zero = col.index(0)
            M = max(col)
            m = sum(col) - M
            if zero == 0:
                answer[3*tkt:3*(tkt+1)] = [0,m,M]
            elif zero == 1:
                answer[3*tkt:3*(tkt+1)] = [m,0,M]
            else:
                answer[3*tkt:3*(tkt+1)] = [m,M,0]
    return answer

def strip():
    answer = 6*27*[None]
    for n in range(9):
        col = column(n)
        for row in range(18):
            answer[9*row+n] = col[row]
    return answer

def printStrip(s):
    index = 0
    for ticket in range(6):
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(9):
                print('%02d '%s[index], end='')
                index += 1
            print()
        print()

printStrip(strip())
```

While I'm not proud of this code (my brain seems to have gone on vacation today) it seems to work.  Here is typical output.

```
09 14 22 00 00 51 63 70 81 
00 17 25 33 40 00 65 77 84 
00 00 27 35 00 00 66 78 87 

03 10 00 00 45 53 61 79 00 
00 11 00 36 00 58 64 00 00 
00 00 20 00 00 59 00 00 90 

07 12 21 00 41 00 69 72 80 
00 00 29 38 43 55 00 00 00 
08 00 00 00 47 00 00 75 00 

01 15 00 00 44 00 62 00 82 
00 16 23 00 00 50 00 76 88 
00 00 28 32 49 54 00 00 89 

04 13 00 30 00 00 00 73 00 
06 19 00 34 42 00 67 00 83 
00 00 24 37 48 57 00 00 86 

02 00 26 31 46 52 60 00 85 
00 18 00 39 00 56 68 71 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 00
```

The double zeroes represent blanks, of course.

Comment: 'If numbers 1,2,3 or 4,5,6, etc. are all picked reject the sample and try again.'

Why is the sample rejected?

Comment: @puskini33 Because we can't have all three rows in a column blank.

Comment: @ saulspatz Do you mean by 1, 2, 3 the position in the column where the number should be placed and when you say 1, 2, 3 you mean all three rows in the column are blank?

Comment: I'm choosing the positions of the blank.  Imagine that the $6$ tickets are placed one above the other, so that the cells in column $1$ say, form a "super-column' $18$ cells long.  I'm choosing where to place the blanks, so $1,2,3$ would mean that all $3$ cells in the column on the first ticket would be blank.  Similarly, $4,5,6$ refers to the cells in the column on the second ticket, and so on.

Comment: @ saulspatz great explanation, I understood. I will try the steps you outlined

Comment: @puskini33 If this answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark, so it no longer shows up as unsolved.

Comment: Your example output is not valid, failing the condition stated as 'A row contains exactly five numbers and four blanks.'

Comment: @DanielMathias You're right.  I completely overlooked that one!  Now I wonder if there's a way to generate tickets other than to continually generate a whole strip and then see if it works.  Clearly, once we figure out where the blanks go, we can generate the ticket.

Comment: Someone with experience in integer linear programming could probably do this quite readily.

Comment: An ILP solution would give only one pattern of blanks.  I gather that the OP wants every possible pattern of blanks to have an equal chance of occurring.  I'm starting to believe that the lottery authority have a small (relatively speaking) number of patterns, and choose one at random from these.  Since one can permute the middle $7$ columns among themselves, and permute the rows of any ticket among themselves, this would still give a vast number of possible strips.

Comment: @puskini33 This turns out to be wrong.  Once you have reviewed it, please un-accept the answer, so that I can delete it.